# Testing iOS app archive and keeping existing sqlite database already in use during development

Tags: objective-c, core-data, icloud

following this link 
[Testing Workflow with Xcode's Archive feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1764/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012028)

I am trying to build and test an iOS app archive.

The application, previously built and developed on iOS devices by means of Xcode, has a Core Data DB that has been filled during development and put in iCloud few months ago.

I would like to develop the archive by keeping the existing DB, however as it is stated in the instruction this seems not possible:

**3) Delete any builds of the app from your device**

and if I am not wrong, deleting the app by device means also delete sqlite file.
I know there's iCloud, but I am not sure the whole sqlite transaction log files are still available.
Do you have any solution or workaround for that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to preserve the data of an app separately from the app itself by using Xcode Organizer.

On the devices tab on the left **under** your device there are several categories. Among Screenshots and Device Logs there is also Applications. The on the main window you can select your application and below *Upload* and *Download* actions for application data are available.

So you can save your data any time and later restore it for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks I know about this option, but you cannot do this when CoreData is in sync with iCloud